# image metadata - flash mode values

Tags: flash, metadata

the 'flash mode' is saved in the image meta-data as a number, what does every value mean in words? How can it be parsed? is their any documentation for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, odd numbers meant the flash fired, even numbers (including zero) meant it did not. There are [other flags](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/privateifd/exif/flash.html) in there as well, such as whether the flash was supposed to fire, and whether the returned light from a flash was detected. Different cameras support different flags, based on their capabilities.

Comment: Is that right for JPG too?

Comment: I believe it is

Comment: 10X